# Query across parents not returning any data

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm making a query on firebase-firestore, but it doesnt return any data
my code is.
 Here is where all categories are printed and where you get the id of each category:

```
<div class="categorias" >
        <a mat-list-item>Categorias</a>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let categoria of categorias | async" routerLink="categorias/{{categoria.id}}">
          <mat-icon>category</mat-icon>
          <span class="sidenav-caption">{{categoria.nome}}</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

this is my query, No error, but no data:

```
produtos: Observable<Produtos[]>;
  produtosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Produtos>;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private produtoService: ProdutosService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
        const categoria = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.produtosCollection = this.afs.collection('produtos', ref => {
          return ref.where('categoria', '==', categoria);
        });
        this.produtos = this.produtosCollection.valueChanges();
      }
```

Only the content of tag h1 is being prepared the rest nothing:

```
<h1>Test </h1>
<div *ngFor="let produto of produtos | async">
    <p>{{produto.descricao}}</p>
</div>
```

[image: for categorias]

[image: for produtos]

[image]

Comment: I know this seems basic, but I gotta ask: are you able to share part of your firestore structure with data in it?

Comment: Please add the image to your question with the `Image` button in the toolbar.

Comment: And using the debugger, you're sure using `const categoria = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');` is returning the value you are expecting?

Comment: @OneLunchMan Yes, is returning the id. See the image

Comment: I know dumb question but: do any of the produtos have that ID as the categoria? Your example just shows the `r14zz...` ID.

Comment: @OneLunchMan, Now I understand that I have to create a method that will receive the param id, then put it in the click event, so every time the user click in a categoria it receive the id and then make the query